# Architecture Components and Intent Extras

Tags: android, mvvm, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

Under the official architecture guidelines, is it still legit to pass data in form of `intent extras` from one `activity` to another (either forward with `startActivity(ForResult)` or back with `setResult`)?

Furthermore, is it okay to populate `views` with this received data (for example with `editText.setText(intent.getStringExtra...)` and make use of the automatic restoration that the Android system handles on configuration changes?

Should any of these responsibilities be forwarded to the `ViewModel` and how?

Comment: I have the same question! Obviously it would be possible to check if the savedinstancestate argument was null in onCreate and if it is, initialize the viewmodel data with the data received through the intent Extras, but I feel that doing so would take away the clean separation of the viewmodel and the view(activity).